# Method issue using switch statement, return not working

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement

Here is the code:

```
    import java.util.*;

public class dayName {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the number to find out what day of the week it represents:");
        int number = in.nextInt();
        weekNumber(number);
    }

    public static String weekNumber(int number)
    {
        String dayNumber;
        switch (number)
        {
        case 1: dayNumber = "Monday"; break;
        case 2: dayNumber = "Tuesday"; break;
        case 3: dayNumber = "Wednesday"; break;
        case 4: dayNumber = "Thursday"; break;
        case 5: dayNumber = "Friday"; break;
        case 6: dayNumber = "Saturday"; break;
        case 7: dayNumber = "Sunday"; break;
        default: dayNumber = ""; break;
        }

        return dayNumber;
    }

}
```

My problem is that it compiles fine but when you ask it the number it doesn't return anything, it should return the day string depending on the number you enter.

Please bear in mind I'm learning Java.

Comment: Add a system.out to display the number that was passed into the weekNumber() method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`weekNumber()` just returns the value but you don't do anything with it.

Change that line to:

```
System.out.println(weekNumber(number));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to write the name to the console:

`System.out.println(weekNumber(number));`

Answer (score 1):

Where are you asking for the number?
if you are asking it in the main method this line of code:

```
weekNumber(number);
```

does not assign your String into a String variable.

Try this in the main method

```
System.out.println(weekNumber(number));
```

Hope this helps!